# Error: template instance error instantiating

Tags: d, vibed

I am trying to display error message if `req` was too short. Here is code:

```
import std.stdio;
import vibe.d;

Database mydatabase;
void main()
{
    // ...
    router.get("*", &myStuff); // all other request
    listenHTTP(settings, router);

    runApplication();

}

@errorDisplay!showPageNotFound
void myStuff(HTTPServerRequest req, HTTPServerResponse res) // I need this to handle any accessed URLs
{
    if(req.path.length > 10) 
    {
    // ...
    }

    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Nothing do not found");
    }
}

void showPageNotFound(string _error = null)
{
    render!("error.dt", _error);
}
```

The error is:

`source\app.d(80,2): Error: template instance app.showPageNotFound.render!("error.dt", _error).render!("app", "app.showPageNotFound") error instantiating`

If I am doing:

```
void showPageNotFound(string _error = null)
{
    res.render!("error.dt", _error);
}
```

I am getting error: 
`Error: undefined identifier 'res'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error above the `error instantiating` one, you'll see that `vibe.d` [tries to call](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/blob/34f1b81242bfa30a5b66faef443500452ca79eac/source/vibe/web/web.d#L295) `init` method of the parent class where `render!` is called, however your code doesn't have a parent class.

This means that currently you can't render any templates in functions called by `errorDisplay` that are outside a class. In fact, when passing `&((new NewWebService).myStuff` to `router.any`, `errorDisplay` doesn't work at all (bug?). All examples in `vibe.d` repository use a class with `errorDisplay`.

---

You could wrap `getStuff` and `showPageNotFound` inside a class, but then `router.any("*", ...` is not a possibility, as it's for individual functions only, and `@path` attribute doesn't support wildcards when used with `registerWebInterface`.

Solution to this would be instead of throwing exception, render the error inside `myStuff`. Albeit a poor one, as I think you wanted to use `errorDisplay`.

A better solution would be implementing functionality in `vibe.d` to pass `req` parameter to functions called by `errorDisplay` (and fixing a bug? that `errorDisplay` can't be used outside a class), or even better, support wildcards in `@path` when used with `registerWebInterface`.